# change users username based on profile custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom field called company name, and I use this to update the field after user registration on my custom sign up page

```
 update_usermeta($user_id, 'user_company_name', $company_name);
```

and I insert users using this code

```
            $userdata = array(
                'user_login' => $email,
                'user_email' => $email,
                'user_pass' => $random_password,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'role' =>  $custom_role,
            );

  $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

what I want to do is to create user username based on `$company_name` , I know it's as simple as changing `'user_login' => $email,` to `'user_login' => $company_name,`
but company names are sometimes too long, including symbols, slash, dash, linking words...etc, and I only want to use the first 2 words devided by underscore... so for example if user company name is (The Stack & Overflow), I want the username to become stack_overflow.

Also is there any way to apply this to current members?

Comment: use regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Source:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Use php's explode function see this example:

```
<?php
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

// Example 2
$data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = explode(":", $data);
echo $user; // foo
echo $pass; // *

?>
```

Comment: Its not fix that " " always there

Answer (score 0):

Remove Special Characters & replace space with _

```
function removeSpecial($string) 
{
   $string = str_replace(' ', '_', $string); // Replaces all spaces with UnderScore.

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

Call function :

```
   echo removeSpecial("stack & Overflow");
```

First we replace underscore with space and then remove special character from string.

Comment: Well, how can I use this exactly the the code above and limit the number of words to 2?

Comment: @Ali_k you can say that word is start with space right

Comment: sorry I didn't understand, let's say I'll use this `$company_name = $cp_name;` the company name is "stack and Overflow with company X" I just want it to return stack_overflow  in the variable `$cp_name`

Comment: Thanks @Vasim, I'll be waiting for your response